# How can I find the IP address of my Router programmatically in Mac OS X or iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, network-programming

I want to be able to find the IP address of my router programmatically in order to perform diagnostics. Is there any way I can find this out using public APIs in Mac OS X and/or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript will let you discover that, I think through the SystemEvents class.

Also, you could use command line tools, like ifconfig, to get information about your current network connections, your router should be the default router for your current subnet, usually X.X.X.1, but not always.

Comment: Neither AppleScript nor ifconfig will work on iOS, which is what I'm really looking for.

Comment: I was more focused on the Mac OS X portion.  I imagine you should be able to find a getHostName() and getHostIP() in the iOS-flavored network.h